# How do I run bash shell commands with subprocess in Python?

Tags: python

I have the follow bash shell command. I want to run it with subprocess.run in python.

```
subprocess.run([.....])
```

Below is bash shell command

```
IFS=$'\n'
for i in $(grep ^id= /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*.nmconnection | cut -d= -f2); do \
    nmcli connection modify "$i" ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname no ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname no; \
done
```

Comment: BTW, that code is not particularly good practice in bash. See [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) -- even after setting IFS you're still prone to glob expansion; a [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) `while IFS== read -r _ I <&3; do ...; done 3< <(grep ...)` loop would be more efficient (doesn't need the `cut` since `read` is doing the work of splitting) and have fewer corner cases

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Why downvote my question? I am beginner. You said It is better to use  this `while IFS= read -r line; do` instead this `IFS=$'\n'` ??

Comment: Not my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

Put it all in a string and then pass that as a the `-c` argument to `bash`.

```
cmd = r"""IFS=$'\n'
for i in $(grep ^id= /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*.nmconnection | cut -d= -f2); do \
    nmcli connection modify "$i" ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname no ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname no; \
done
"""
subprocess.run(["bash", "-c", cmd])
```

Comment: Probably want to make it a raw string

Comment: @Barman what is "r" right of cmd?  `cmd = r`

Comment: That's the beginning of a raw string literal. It's needed so that `\n` inside the string will not be treated as an escape sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than run the bash script directly in the `subprocess.run` call, you could perform the looping in Python.

One way to do this would be:

```py
import glob
import re

cmd_pre = "nmcli connection modify"
cmd_suf = "ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname no ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname no"
glob_str = "/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*.nmconnection"
regex = re.compile(r"id=(\w+)")

for fn in glob.glob(glob_str):
    matches = [re.match(regex, l) for l in open(fn)]
    names = [m.groups(1)[0] for m in matches if m is not None]
    for name in names:
        subprocess.run(" ".join([cmd_pre, name, cmd_suf]))
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'cmd_suf' is not defined`

Comment: It doesn't work Please check your errors. Thank you

Comment: That is an older version you're referring to. Try the current one.

Comment: It doesn't work. There is a fault in you code. I tried a lot of times.

Comment: There may be an issue with the specification of the problem. As I see it, you are looking for lines in the files contiained in the glob `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*.nmconnection` that start with "`id=`" and you wish to take the next word after the `=` character and pass those to the `nmcli` command. This works on a test set of files that I generated myself. If you could provide an example file or a part of an example file it might be possible to see what the difference is between what I wrote above and what you are expecting.

Comment: this is the error message. `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nmcli connection modify Wired ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname no ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname no'`

Comment: This would indicate that nmcli is not in the standard path. You may replace `nmcli` with the result of running `which nmcli` in the shell (the absolute path of the command, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/nmcli`).